# Highchart: Only show one series at a time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to only show one series at a time.
Also I want to disable the option to show no series at all.

I found this: http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6399
But the answer does not work.

Comment: Can you share the code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Apperently admin posted this as a solution http://jsfiddle.net/tK38J/8/ but this does not work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ctjM7/ check this

Comment: It works. Thank you very much! Another thing I can't figure out is I want to disable the option to show no series at all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was using outdated Highcharts url and old version of jQuery. To disable possibility for hiding series use `legendItemClick`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/tK38J/65/

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      show: function () {
        var chart = this.chart,
            series = chart.series,
            i = series.length,
            otherSeries;

        while (i--) {
          otherSeries = series[i];
          if (otherSeries != this && otherSeries.visible) {
            otherSeries.hide();
          }
        }
      },
      legendItemClick: function () {
        if (this.visible) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks @Pawel Fus

Answer (score 0):

A more compact way of doing it. And it also works with multiple series which are combined in one legend item.

```
                    events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        if (this.visible) {
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            let series = this.chart.series,
                                i = series.length,
                                otherSeries;
                            while(i--) {
                                otherSeries = series[i]
                                if (otherSeries != this && otherSeries.visible) {
                                    otherSeries.hide();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
```